# How to keep Python script running in the background and "contact" it with information?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian-based

I'm still fairly new to programming, so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I'm working on a project (star tracking) in which speed is of paramount importance. Once an image is taken, I need the Python script I have to analyze the image and return the results as soon as possible.

While the analysis itself happens very fast, I can't afford to wait the 10-20 seconds it takes for the Python script to start running every time a photo is taken.

I am instead envisioning a system where the script is started once, and as soon as the initialization sequence is complete the process is backgrounded. The script then "listens" for commands sent to it (ie. "here's a path to a new image, analyze it and report back the results"), and then responds appropriately.

But I have no idea how something like this would be implemented. Any help at all here would be much appreciated. (This will all be happening on Debian or some derivative of it.)

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: One route to consider is using S3 and Lambda functions on AWS. Your python lambda function would listen for an object created event in your specified S3 path and would be invoked as soon as it sees a new object (image in your case). Here's a link to the "using lambda with s3 docs" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: Why does it take 10-20 seconds for the script to start running? I'd address that first, as it seems like it'd be low-hanging fruit.

Comment: @Brayden That would be nice, but this is going on an open-source satellite, so that's not really an option, haha.

Comment: @kindall Well, I guess I should have specified that this one Python script is part of a larger network of Python and C code and Swig is used to connect it all up, so I don't know how much headway can be made there. Ideally it would take <0.5 seconds, and I don't know if the startup time of something this big can be reduced that far. Also, there's a couple seconds of inititialization within the Python script as it loads a star catalog, and there's no way to reduce that, so I don't think there's a whole lot to be done on that front.

Comment: Something like this looks promising https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog. I've never used it myself, but the example they have looks like your exact use-case: monitor contents of directory and then do some processing when the contents change.

Comment: You can use a simple socket to inform your 'background' script that a new photo is available. The question is how do you know that a photo has been taken and can you execute something at that time?